# What is the difference between SynchronizedCollection<T> and the other concurrent collections?

Tags: c#, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrent-collections, synchronizedcollection

How does `SynchronizedCollection<T>` and the concurrent collections in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace differ from each other, apart from Concurrent Collections being a namespace and `SynchronizedCollection<T>` being a class?

`SynchronizedCollection<T>` and all of the classes in Concurrent Collections provide thread-safe collections. How do I decide when to use one over the other, and why?

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946520/why-are-there-no-concurrent-collections-in-c

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The **[`SynchronizedCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx)** class was introduced first in .NET 2.0 to provide a thread-safe collection class. It does this via locking so that you essentially have a `List<T>` where every access is wrapped in a `lock` statement.

The **[`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx)** namespace is much newer. It wasn't introduced until .NET 4.0 and it includes a substantially improved and more diverse set of choices. These classes no longer use locks to provide thread safety, which means they should scale better in a situation where multiple threads are accessing their data simultaneously. However, a class implementing the `IList<T>` interface is notably absent among these options.

So, if you're targeting version 4.0 of the .NET Framework, you should use one of the collections provided by the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace whenever possible. Just as with choosing between the various types of collections provided in the [`System.Collections.Generic` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx), you'll need to choose the one whose features and characteristics best fit your specific needs.

If you're targeting an older version of the .NET Framework or need a collection class that implements the `IList<T>` interface, you'll have to opt for the `SynchronizedCollection<T>` class.

This article on MSDN is also worth a read: [When to Use a Thread-Safe Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997373.aspx)

Comment: So, I can prefer System.Collections.Concurrent over SynchrinozedCollecction<T> as I am using version 4.0!!

Comment: If these new Concurrent collections do not use locks for thread safety, how is the concurrency achieved?

Comment: @Matt: Various ways. The answer is probably complicated enough so as to merit its own question. But for inspiration, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688870/how-might-a-class-like-nets-concurrentbagt-be-implemented and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785622/why-is-concurrentbagt-so-slow-in-net-4-0-am-i-doing-it-wrong (Also, did you read the MSDN article that I linked to? It gives a very brief summary of the tricks they use instead of locking, albeit probably not enough to write your own implementation.)

Comment: thanks for the info.  That was a good hour or so of reading about things I had no idea even existed in .NET (and still don't fully comprehend)

Comment: @Matt, the .NET4 concurrent classes use SpinWait objects to address thread-safety instead of Monitor.Enter/Exit (aka Critical section).  The difference is that SpinWait structures try to keep the thread running and waiting for a signal to continue, whereas a Critical section does a yield (aka thread-context switch) and then periodically returns back to the thread and checks to see if it can continue.  CS's are fast, but in some situations, a SpinWait results in better performance if the guarded code executes fast.

Comment: As far as I can see, there still is no concurrent IList<T> alternative to this day. In a ConcurrentBag you can't really remove items. Some articles suggest (ab-)using a ConcurrentDictionary, which I find irritating due to its unnecessary overhead. So I myself keep using SynchronizedCollection.

Answer (score 7):

The [`SynchronizedCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.synchronizedcollection-1) is a synchronized [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1). It's a concept that can be devised in a second, and can be [implemented fully](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/1a291ea424991a184ffafd2ba20928e0e339fb96/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/SynchronizedCollection.cs) in about one hour. Just wrap each method of a `List<T>` inside a `lock (this)`, and you are done. Now you have a thread-safe collection, that can cover all the needs of a multithreaded application. Except that it doesn't.

The shortcomings of the `SynchronizedCollection<T>` become apparent as soon as you try to do anything non-trivial with it. Specifically as soon as you try to combine two or more methods of the collection for a  conceptually singular operation. Then you realize that the operation is not atomic, and cannot be made atomic without resorting to explicit synchronization (locking on the [`SyncRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.synchronizedcollection-1.syncroot) property of the collection), which undermines the whole purpose of the collection. Some examples:

1. Ensure that the collection contains unique elements: `if (!collection.Contains(x)) collection.Add(x);`. This code ensures nothing. The inherent race condition between `Contains` and `Add` allows duplicates to occur.
2. Ensure that the collection contains at most N elements: `if (collection.Count < N) collection.Add(x);`. The race condition between `Count` and `Add` allows more than N elements in the collection.
3. Replace `"Foo"` with `"Bar"`: `int index = collection.IndexOf("Foo"); if (index >= 0) collection[index] = "Bar";`. When a thread reads the `index`, its value is immediately stale. Another thread might change the collection in a way that the `index` points to some other element, or it's out of range.

At this point you realize that multithreading is more demanding than what you originally thought. Adding a layer of synchronization around the API of an existing collection doesn't cut it. You need a collection that is designed from the ground up for multithreaded usage, and has an API that reflects this design. This was the motivation for the introduction of the [concurrent collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) in .NET Framework 4.0.

The concurrent collections, for example the [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) and the [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2), are highly sophisticated components. They are orders of magnitude more sophisticated than the clumsy `SynchronizedCollection<T>`. They are equipped with special atomic APIs that are well suited for multithreaded environments (`TryDequeue`, `GetOrAdd`, `AddOrUpdate` etc), and also with implementations that aim at minimizing the contention under heavy usage. Internally they employ lock-free, low-lock and granular-lock techniques. Learning how to use these collections requires some study. They are not direct drop-in replacements of their non-concurrent counterparts.

**Caution:** the enumeration of a `SynchronizedCollection<T>` is not synchronized. Getting an enumerator with `GetEnumerator` is synchronized, but using the enumerator is not. So if one thread does a `foreach (var item in collection)` while another thread mutates the collection in any way (`Add`, `Remove` etc), the behavior of the program is undefined. The safe way to enumerate a `SynchronizedCollection<T>` is to get a snapshot of the collection, and then enumerate the snapshot. Getting a snapshot is not trivial, because it involves two method calls (the `Count` getter and the [`CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.synchronizedcollection-1.copyto)), so explicit synchronization is required. Beware of the LINQ [`ToArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) operator, it's not thread-safe by itself. Below is a safe `ToArraySafe` extension method for the `SynchronizedCollection<T>` class:

```
/// <summary>Copies the elements of the collection to a new array.</summary>
public static T[] ToArraySafe<T>(this SynchronizedCollection<T> source)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    lock (source.SyncRoot)
    {
        T[] array = new T[source.Count];
        source.CopyTo(array, 0);
        return array;
    }
}
```