# ConcurrentKeyedCollection approach

Tags: c#, collections, concurrent-collections

Id like to make use of a ConcurrentKeyedCollection - but it doesn't exist.
Why no ConcurrentKeyedCollection?
What should I be using? (ConcurrentDictionary? Wrap my own concurrency protection around a KeyedCollection?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SynchronizedKeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668294.aspx) introduced in .NET 2.0 does the job - using a List and wrapping access in a lock.  Note that the newer "Concurrent" collections introduced in .NET 4.0 used an improved mechanism and should scale better - but they dont offer a KeyedCollection.  More info on "Synchronized" vs "Concurrent" collections [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655150/what-is-the-difference-between-synchronizedcollectiont-and-the-other-concurren).

Comment: Is this still true in 2022 regarding the Concurrent Collection ?